# jquery removing event listener not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

I have an outer div, inside that there is an inner div (which is actually 1/4 in size of its parent). initially the inner div is positioned at the top left corner. what i'm doing is, when outer div gets a `mouseenter` event, the inner div will move to bottom left corner, and when the outer div gets a `mouseleave` event, the inner div will wait for 1 second then it will move back to its original position. normally my code is working. but there is a special situation, for example i hover my mouse on outer div, then in less than one second i hover out and hover in back on it again. for this kind of situation i'm canceling the `mouseleave` event with `.off()` method in the beginning of the `mouseenter` event. but its not working.

```js
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
$(outer).on('mouseenter', () => {
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $(inner).css("transform", "translateY(0)");
    });

    $(outer).on('mouseleave', () => {
        $(this).delay(1000).queue((next) => {
            $(inner).css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
            next();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; position: fixed; background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div id="inner" style = "width: 50px; height: 50px; position: fixed; background-color: yellow; transition: all 0.5s;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that you call `off()`, the event has already been triggered and is being delayed. You instead need to remove the queued animation with the `dequeue()` method.

```js
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");
$(outer).on('mouseenter', () => {
        $(this).dequeue();
        $(inner).css("transform", "translateY(0)");
    });

    $(outer).on('mouseleave', () => {
        $(this).delay(1000).queue((next) => {
            $(inner).css("transform", "translateY(100%)");
            next();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; position: fixed; background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black;">
    <div id="inner" style = "width: 50px; height: 50px; position: fixed; background-color: yellow; transition: all 0.5s;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you hover over the blue square, the yellow square moves to the top left, and when you exit the blue square with your mouse it moves back to the bottom left. In the example provided with the question, quickly moving your mouse outside of the bounds of the blue square and back in again causes the yellow square to return to the bottom left, where it should not be while your mouse is inside the blue square.